# JTextPane insert component, faulty vertical alignment

Tags: java, vertical-alignment, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane, into which I need to insert a JComponent. I'm using

```
JTextPane.insertComponent(Component)
```

The item is indeed inserted, but the vertical positioning is too high. Instead of having the bottom of the component aligned with the baseline of the current line of text, the component is way above that position, blocking out/over-painting lines of text appearing above.

I have tried calling setAlignmentY(float) with various values, on both the inserted component and the JTextPane, but it doesn't affect the behavior at all.

My guess: there seems to be some state inside my JTextPane or its Document that I need to be changing. But I don't know what it is.

Comment: [Using Text Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html).

Comment: The problem has disappeared. Another person on the team backed out some changes related to "zooming" text in the text pane. Unfortunately, I can't tell you what aspects of that code were the cause of the undesirable behaviour.

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted. I have experienced similar problems related to Swing components. Someone has made a change to one component and this messes up all the others.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `setSize(width, height)` on the JComponent before you insert it into the JTextPane? It should work for most components.

Comment: Didn't have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is a pretty old question, but your approach of using setAlignmentY is totally correct. Don't know what code caused it to not work, but the javadoc of JTextPane.insertComponent(Component) says the following about the alignment:

> The component is placed relative to the text baseline according to the
>   value returned by Component.getAlignmentY. For Swing components this
>   value can be conveniently set using the method
>   JComponent.setAlignmentY. For example, setting a value of 0.75 will
>   cause 75 percent of the component to be above the baseline, and 25
>   percent of the component to be below the baseline

So using `textPane.setAlignmentY(1.0f)` has the desired effect.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem and could not find a solution using JTextPane or JEditorPane.  But I was able to use JavaFX/WebView/WebEngine/JFXPanel.  You will need to update to Java 8 (JDK 1.8).  I made my own class HTMLPaneType, an extension of JFXPanel, and use HTMLPaneType in place of a JTextPane.

A JTextPane requires adding a HyperlinkListener if you want to respond to href clicks.  HTMLPaneType requires adding a listener if you want to NOT respond to href clicks or to respond differently.  In my case, I wanted to launch an external browser on an href click.  I was able to do that with both the JTextPane and the extended JFXPanel.  See also
http://blogs.kiyut.com/tonny/2013/07/30/javafx-webview-addhyperlinklistener/#.VK-JIHsueWN

Comment: The point is there might not be a solution to the alignment problem using a JTextPane/JEditorPane.  The orig poster said "I have tried calling setAlignmentY(float) with various values, on both the inserted component and the JTextPane, but it doesn't affect the behavior at all." so textPane.setAlignmentY(1.0f) might not work.  If that is the case, then one should consider the JavaFX/WebView/WebEngine/JFXPanel approach.  This is the more modern method anyway.